# Keyboard disappearing(closing) after every keystroke in react-native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-flatlist, textinput

I am working on small react-native component and I faced this problem related with TextInput field that is used with Flatlist. so I basically have a flatlist, that renders a list of comments on a post and at the bottom of the screen, I have a TextInput field(its postion is absolute) where users can comment on the post. The problem I am facing is that when I try to type on the input field, the keyboard disappears(or closes) after the first keystroke. I don't know what is causing this problem even after trying many possible suggested solutions(like the key to the flatlist render should not be random etc). I have put the whole code below for reference. I look forward to your suggestions or refernces on how to solve it.

```
import { View, Text,TouchableOpacity,Image,SafeAreaView, FlatList, TextInput, KeyboardAvoidingView, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native'
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import CommentDat from '../Src/CommentDat';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
export default function Comment() {
    const [txt,settxt] = useState("")
    const [sndbtn,setsendbtn] = useState(false)
    const FlatlistHeader=()=>{
        return (
            <View style={{paddingVertical: 12,paddingHorizontal: 12,alignItems:"stretch"}}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor:"grey",width: 100,borderRadius: 6}}><Text style={{color: "white",textAlign: "center"}}>{CommentDat[0].postType}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity style={{flexDirection: "row",marginTop: 12}}>
                    <Image style={{height: 40,width: 40,borderRadius: 20}} source={{uri:CommentDat[0].photo }} />
                    <View style={{flexDirection:"column",marginLeft: 12}}>
                        <Text style={{fontWeight: "bold",fontSize: 18}}>{CommentDat[0].author}</Text>
                        <Text>address num.Views and times viewed</Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <View style={{marginTop: 12}}>
                    <Text style={{fontWeight: "bold",fontSize: 18}}>{CommentDat[0].title}</Text>
                    <Text>{CommentDat[0].context}</Text>
                </View>
                {/* here we show times viewed and stuff */}
                <View style={{flexDirection: "row",justifyContent: "space-around",marginTop: 16}}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{flexDirection: "row",alignItems:"center"}}>
                        <Icon name='md-thumbs-up-outline' />
                        <Text style={{marginLeft: 5}}>share</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{flexDirection: "row",alignItems:"center"}}>
                        <Icon name='md-chatbubble-outline' />
                        <Text style={{marginLeft: 5}}>comment</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{flexDirection: "row",alignItems:"center"}}>
                        <Icon name='heart-outline' />
                        <Text style={{marginLeft: 5}}>Interest</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

            </View>
        )
    }
    // const handleTxtChange = React.useCallback((text) => {
    //   settxt(text);
    // }, []);
    // const HanldeSendbtn =()=>{
    //     setsendbtn(true)
    // }
    const sndColor = txt?"red":"grey"

    const CommentView = ({item,index}) => {
        return (
          <View>
          <View key={index} style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', marginVertical: 10,justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={{flexDirection: "row",marginLeft: 8}}>
            <Image source={{ uri: item.photo }} style={{ width: 50, height: 50, borderRadius: 25, marginRight: 10 }} />
            <View style={{ flexDirection: "column" }}>
              <Text style={{fontWeight: "bold",fontSize: 18}}>{item.author}</Text>
              <Text>{item.address} . {item.timePost}hrs. ago</Text>
            </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity><Icon name='ellipsis-vertical' /></TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
           <View style={{paddingHorizontal: 68}}>
              <Text>{item.context}</Text>
              <View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{flexDirection: "row",alignItems:"center"}}>
                        <Icon name='md-thumbs-up-outline' />
                        <Text style={{marginLeft: 5}}>like</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{flexDirection: "row",alignItems:"center",marginLeft: 18}}>
                        <Icon name='md-chatbubble-outline' />
                        <Text style={{marginLeft: 5}}>comment</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        );
      };
    const FlastlistFooter =() =>{
        return (
            <View style={{position: "absolute",bottom: 0,backgroundColor: '#fff',flexDirection: "row",alignItems:"center",width: "100%"}}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={{marginLeft: 16}}><Icon name='image-outline' size={28}/></TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity style={{marginLeft: 6}}><Icon name='location-outline' size={28}/></TouchableOpacity>
                  <TextInput
                  style={{height: 36,width: 260,margin: 12,borderWidth: 1,borderRadius: 20, padding: 10,}}
                  placeholder='write your comment'
                  value={txt}
                  onChangeText={v=>settxt(v)}
                  // onEndEditing={()=>onchange(txt)}
                  // onFocus={HanldeSendbtn}
                  />
                {sndbtn?<TouchableOpacity>{sndbtn?<Icon color={sndColor} name='send' size={28}/>:null}</TouchableOpacity>:null} 
            </View>
        )
    }
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <FlatList
        contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 100 }}
        ListHeaderComponent={FlatlistHeader}
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
        data={CommentDat[0].list_comment}
        renderItem={CommentView}
      />
      
      <FlastlistFooter/>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

Comment: Try replace `<FlastlistFooter/>` by `{FlastlistFooter()}`.

Comment: @kiuQ This actually worked for me but I actually don't understand how the two differ and how it could solve the problem I was facing. Could you explain a little more on how the two differ and why it worked? thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I have the correct explaination or not, please point out if it is incorrect.

This is related to **react component lifecycle**.

When you type inside the textInput and trigger state change, your functional component `Comment()` will re-render the whole body includes defined component. You may know more in [here](https://dev.to/borasvm/react-create-component-inside-a-component-456b).

To prevent that, you can

1. simply replace `<FlastlistFooter/>` by `{FlastlistFooter()}`.
2. Or move the defined component out of the parent component like following.

```
const FlastlistFooter =({value, onChangeText}) =>{
    //Move FlastlistFooter outside Comment()
    return (
        <View style={{position: "absolute",bottom: 0,backgroundColor: '#fff',flexDirection: "row",alignItems:"center",width: "100%"}}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={{marginLeft: 16}}><Icon name='image-outline' size={28}/></TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={{marginLeft: 6}}><Icon name='location-outline' size={28}/></TouchableOpacity>
              <TextInput
              style={{height: 36,width: 260,margin: 12,borderWidth: 1,borderRadius: 20, padding: 10,}}
              placeholder='write your comment'
              value={value}
              onChangeText={onChangeText}
              // onEndEditing={()=>onchange(txt)}
              // onFocus={HanldeSendbtn}
              />
            {sndbtn?<TouchableOpacity>{sndbtn?<Icon color={sndColor} name='send' size={28}/>:null}</TouchableOpacity>:null} 
        </View>
    )
}

export default function Comment() {
    const [txt,settxt] = useState("")
    const [sndbtn,setsendbtn] = useState(false)
    
    ...

    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <FlatList
          contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 100 }}
          ListHeaderComponent={FlatlistHeader}
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
          data={CommentDat[0].list_comment}
          renderItem={CommentView}
        />
      
        <FlastlistFooter
          value={txt}
          onChangeText={v=>settxt(v)}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
 }
```

Comment: yea you actually are right, the problem was it was re-rendering the component as the state of txt was changing.  https://levelup.gitconnected.com/code-review-avoid-declaring-react-component-inside-parent-component-1768a645f523  this article also says it all. i hope it helps sb. while reading it i got another question. if we just use <TextInput .../> directly in the Comment, it works fine. but when the states change, doesn't <TextInput /> also get refreshed and lose the keyboard? or I am missing some bigger picture and understanding of how React works?

Comment: That is a pretty good question, I am not sure about the answer. I guess the reason behind is like the solution 2 that passes state as props to another component. Or react-native library did something inside all basic components.